# How do I create a list of multiple columns of a file depending on row index?

Tags: python, list

I'm not a programmer and use python for analyzing electrical grid over powerfactory.
I have a result of a simulation, to deal with there is a bunch of functions which belong to PowerFactory. This result contains  around 3000 columns X 3000 rows. I need to extract a definite columns to deal with.( I can't do that from powerfactory before simulation)
For Ex. my result:

```
Bus0     Bus1     Bus2    ....   Bus3000
0        0        0              0
1        1        1              1
2        2        2              2
..       ..       ..             ..
3000     3000     3000           3000
```

How to create a list, which contains only for ex.;

```
Bus0        Bus2     
0           0             
1           1             
2           2             
..          ..             
3000        3000
```

Thank you

Comment: What format is the data in? Is it plain text as shown in your post or is it something else? If plain text, then the csvreader module should be able to parse this

Comment: I'm afraid this is too broad for the Stack overflow Q&A format,  suggest you look into the `pandas` library for dealing with this sort of data. e.g. https://datascienceparichay.com/article/read-csv-files-using-pandas-with-examples

Answer (score 0):

Actually it depends on a bunch of orders which concern with both of PowerFactory and Python.

1. Export a class of objects from result of a simulation (For Ex. `AllBB`)
2. To create a list of definite Busbars, the codes of these elements have to be known which probably depend on sorting of the elements in Project.

```py
import numpy
BB_List = numpy.array([AllBB[0], AllBB[2]])
```

3. To deal only with this list, for ex. to read the max. and min voltages on these busbars over a period of time (day, month or a year)

```py
for BB in (BB_List):
    Voltage = Result.FindColumn(BB,'m:u1)
    Max_Voltage = Result.FindMaxInColumn(Voltage)
    Min_Voltage = result.FindMinInColumn(Voltage)
```